# LogCat on Samsung Galaxy S4

Tags: android, logcat, galaxy

I am in a process of developing an Android app ... Therefore I have tested everything on my 3 android phones and everything was fine... I asked some friends to play with the app and app crushes...

I tried to use LogCat to receive errors on Galaxy S4 but it is impossible because log list is flooded by:

`AbsListView D unregisterIRListner() is called`

This happens every 0.1 second... All apps (expect CatLog 1.4.4) ... I've tried already resetting the phone, clearing apps cache, ...

Any idea?

Comment: use ACRA and send logs and crash reports to your email address )

Answer (score 1):

Interesting. Can you see which app spawns the console. Anyway, for your problem. You can add filters to LogCat, thus only showing the information of your app. So for example you can use the `TAG` to filter your messages:

```
private static final String TAG = "MyActivity";
Log.v(TAG, "index=" + i);
```

And then use this command to filter:

```
adb logcat -s MyActivity
```

Its much easier to do this in an IDE. ;) You can find much more information on using logcat especially with console command [here](http://developer.android.com/tools/debugging/debugging-log.html).

Comment: Thanks, I tried this and it is OK ... but anyway ... this error bothers me ... What is wrong with S4?! :)

Answer (score 1):

For this kind of situations, i recommend [ACRA - automatic crash reporting library](https://github.com/ACRA/acra). It is very easy to configure.

How it works? Everytime your app crashes, it automatically sends stacktrace along with tons of other information to GoogleDoc form. Very useful tool, when you give your application to testers. It can even be configured to show dialog asking user if he wants to send crash log, and write some comment on what he was doing when app crashed...

Comment: Have you ever tried to implement it? I have MainActivity that extends activity already...

Comment: Yes i am using it in several applications. What problem do you have?

Comment: With ACRA your MainActivity can extend what you want. Its MyApplication class that you need to configure.

Comment: In acra's docs it is said that I have to make new class that extend Application... and add org.acra.* and org.acra.annotation.* = https://github.com/ACRA/acra/wiki/BasicSetup 

But I get: The import org.acra.annotation cannot be resolved

Comment: Have you included ACRA library in your project?

Comment: Jup ... JAR - acra-2.0.3.jar

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41941/discussion-between-m-v-and-smitalm)